# how to query to get desired data

Tags: sql, group-by

here below is mt database table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mtblLog_Book](
[Logbook_Number] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Sno] [int] NULL,
[Vehicle_Number] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Vehicle_Booking_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Time_From] [datetime] NULL,
[Time_To] [datetime] NULL,
[KM_Start] [int] NULL,
[KM_End] [int] NULL,
[Total] [int] NULL,
[Vehicle_Used_By] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Cost_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Budget_Line] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Entry_Date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

there are repeated `Cost_Code`. I need a query so that I can get a data in the below format

```
CostCode1
......................
All data which belong to CostCode1
......................

CostCode2
......................
All data which belong to CostCode2
......................

CostCode3
......................
All data which belong to CostCode3
......................
```

Cont.... to CostCode**n**

Thanks

Comment: you cant print out headlines in between. In Sql every query result have to have the same amount of coloums. so what about `SELECT * FROM dbo.mtblLog_Book ORDER BY Cost_Code`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display like the way you have shown above.thn use this code

```
    protected void show()
    {
     Response.Clear();
     string sql = "select Cost_Code from mtblLog_Book";
     ds = obj.openDataset(sql, schoolCode);

     if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
     {
        Response.Write("[{\"Records\":\"" + "NA" + "\"}]");
     }
     else
     {
        int i;
        string output;
        for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
        string sqlOutput ="Select * from mtblLog_Book where CostCode='"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][ "CostCode"].ToString()+ "';";
            Dataset dsOutPut= new Dataset;
          output = "[{\" Logbook_Number \":\"" +dsOutPut.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Logbook_Number"].ToString() + "\",\" Sno\": \"" + dsOutPut.Tables[0].Rows[i][" Sno"] + "\",\" Vehicle_Number\": \"" + dsOutPut.Tables[0].Rows[i][" Vehicle_Number"].ToString() + "\",\" Vehicle_Booking_Date\": \"" + dsOutPut.Tables[0].Rows[i][" Vehicle_Booking_Date"].ToString() + "\" }]"

            Response.Write(output);
            if (i < dsOutPut.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                Response.Write("\n");
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server and SSMS you could set it to output results to text and do something like

```
DECLARE @costCode NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT Cost_Code
FROM dbo.mtblLog_Book

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @costCode
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    PRINT @costCode
    PRINT '......................................'
    SELECT * FROM dbo.mtblLog_Book
    WHERE Cost_Code = @costCode
    PRINT '......................................'
              PRINT ''  
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Then copy and paste the result to wherever you need it

Comment: it is not stoppable. it runs to infinity